# Laser-like pointer for PDF Viewer

Tags: pdf

I have some slides in PDF format. I need to show them through Skype (screen sharing). Is there any PDF viewer in Ubuntu that provides the possibility to have some kind of laser-like pointer to show/underline parts of my slides?

Comment: You can change the appearance of the cursor using Unity Tweak Tool. Go to `Appearance` > `Cursor` and set it to `Redglass`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a cursor theme that looks like a laser pointer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347170/is-there-a-cursor-theme-that-looks-like-a-laser-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

Okular allows draw over PDF. Not a laser-mode, but similar to requirement