# How to make the mouse cursor look like a laser pointer in Ubuntu?

Tags: cursor-theme

I have to give a presentation, and I want to make the cursor look like a laser pointer.

It seems that Libreoffice Impress [cannot do](https://askubuntu.com/q/1195795/124466) it.

Instead, I want to change the cursor theme temporarily during the presentation so that the mouse pointer looks like a laser beam.
Is there a theme like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### GoogleDot Red Cursor

You can use [GoogleDot Red Cursor theme](https://github.com/ful1e5/Google_Cursor/issues/21), which features a circular red mouse pointer.

First, download the latest `GoogleDot-Red.tar.gz` from https://github.com/ful1e5/Google_Cursor/releases.

Then, run the following commands to extract and install it.

```
tar -xvf GoogleDot-Red.tar.gz
mv GoogleDot-* ~/.icons/
```

Finally, change the cursor in settings.

[image: googledotred]

---

### Alternative cursor

Below maybe not what you really want, but it is a good workaround.

Install `xcursor-themes` package by

```
sudo apt-get install xcursor-themes
```

and temporarily switch to some red theme by keyboard shortcut.
Below are the scripts for setting up a keyboard shortcut to change the cursor in MATE DE, you can adapt them for other DEs.

Script for cursor theme toggling:

```
mkdir ~/bin
cat <<EOF > ~/bin/toggle-pointer.sh
if gsettings get org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-theme | grep -q default
then
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-theme 'oxy-red-argentina'; 
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-size 48;
else
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-theme 'default'; 
    gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse cursor-size 24;
fi
EOF

chmod +x ~/bin/toggle-pointer.sh
```

Note: if you know cursor theme then replace `oxy-red-argentina` with known name.

Command to bind the above script to the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (as example) shortcut:

```
dconf load / <<EOF
[org/mate/desktop/keybindings/custom99]
action='/home/$USER/bin/toggle-pointer.sh'
binding='<Mod4>b'
name='ToggleCursorTheme'
EOF
```

This will work as follows:

[image: beam]

Comment: I would happily change the cursor before the presentation, and this keyboard shortcut is a bonus!

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. This theme is so cool.

Answer (score -1):

A link below to download WPS Office
[Download Wps for linux](https://www.wps.com/download)

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use WPS office. It is not a free software. I want to use a cursor theme that looks like a laser pointer.